# Vagrant Remote Box Setup

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, puppet, ansible

I have a requirement to setup VM boxes across multiple host machines and this has to be initiated from a single master host. To elaborate bit more, I will have VM templates with different configurations (created as say a VgrantFile) and the master host should initiate connection to the child host and bring up the VM based on a specific template.

Can I use Vagrant for this ? Appreciate if you can suggest alternatives.

Regards

Comment: What kind of hypervisors hosts ? VirtualBox, vSphere, xen, kvm ? There's a lot of plugins for vagrant, but I've no divination skills, hard to help without the use case...

Comment: The use case is simple. We want provision VMs on remote hosts with virtualbox/KVM. You can consider remote hosts as offshore development Center where a high capacity host machine is deployed. We would like to push standard VMs to the offshore host machine from onshore control center for various users (development, support, project management etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I found according to your description:

https://github.com/fjsanpedro/vagrant-nodemaster

https://github.com/fjsanpedro/vagrant-node

Comment: Thanks Tensibai ! Can I use this along with a vagrantfile . This seem to be a vagrant CLI option to control guest VMs remotely. I am more interested in defining a template for each type of guest machine using a vagrant file.

Comment: Also would like to know if the communication between master and node is secure since by default it listens on port 3333 and most probably this port will be blocked by firewall.

Comment: @user3364247 I've no idea, I'm not using it. It's what I found with a simple google search.